# C# call return type with different type of var for argument

Tags: c#, variables, parameter-passing

I have a struct with some properties. 
Some of these properties are set to a type of variable like string int etc. 
But there is one variable that needs to accept different types of variables. I have tried the following:

```
public class Test{

    Public Generate_Scentence(){
        Answer new = set_values("test", SomeTypeOfVariable);
        //some use case examples:
        Answer new2 = set_values("test2", "test2");
        Answer new2 = set_values("test3", 48584);
        Answer new2 = set_values("test4", 4.4f);
        Answer new2 = set_values("test5", CustomClass a);
        //etc etc
    }


    public struct Answer{
        public string read;
        public System.Object val;
    }

    public Answer set_values(string t, System.Object v){
        Answer a = new Answer();
        a.read = t;
        a.val = v;
        return a;
    }


}
```

In this case `SomeTypeOfVariable` should accept types like:

```
string something
int something
CustomClass something
float something 
etc etc
```

In javascript i could just do:

```
var something = whateveriputhere
```

I cant seem to figure out how to do this. I am really only familiar with javascript this is my first time in c#. So sorry if this is not correct or a weird question.

If something is unclear let me know so i can clarify.

Comment: Your talking about basic inheritance and generic methods. Can you elaborate on what you really want to accomplish, maybe with pseudo code you could make more clear?

Comment: In c# also you can define it as var **I meant variable, didn't read the question carefully** !

Comment: @kaj You cannot define a field or property as a `var`

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't meant a field. just a variable, thanks @juharr

Comment: @kaj But they can declare it as Object and use reflection to get it's type for casting purposes.

Comment: First, I'd suggest creating a class instead of a `struct` here because mutable structs are just asking for problems.  Then create properties instead of fields.  Finally you could make this generic, but it's not clear why you need to have a bunch of different types.

Comment: @JSteward I added some examples of the uses in the question hopefully this helps to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a generic struct/class and a generic function:

```
public class Test
{

    public void Generate_Scentence()
    {
        var new1 = set_values("test", new SomeTypeOfVariable());
        var new2 = set_values("test2", "test2");
        var new3 = set_values("test3", 48584);
        var new4 = set_values("test4", 4.4f);
        var new5 = set_values("test5", new CustomClass());
        //etc etc
    }


    public Answer<TData> set_values<TData>(string t, TData v)
    {
        var a = new Answer<TData>();
        a.Read = t;
        a.Val = v;
        return a;
    }
}

public struct Answer<TData>
{
    public string Read { get; set; }
    public TData Val { get; set; }
}

public class SomeTypeOfVariable { }
public class CustomClass { }
```

Comment: Why class and not struct?

Comment: @DavidG Good catch, I guess my fingers only know how to type `class`, I'll fix it.

Comment: I would think a class would be better if you're using generics. Structs should be immutable.

Comment: @RufusL I would tend to agree with you but I'll leave that detail to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple functions with the same name that take different types its called function overloading.

```
public Answer set_values(string t, string v){...}
public Answer set_values(string t, int v){...}
```

However that doesn't solve the problem of how to store the data in an Answer object.  The most common solution to that problem is using [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/).

```
public class Answer<T>
{
    T val {get;set;}
...
}
```

you can then define you set_values to return an Answer T

```
public Answer<string> set_values(string t, string v){...}
public Answer<int> set_values(string t, int v){...}
```

As someone pointed out in the comments you can also make set_values generic itself if you are not doing anything specific based upon the type.

```
public Answer<T> set_values<T>(string t, T value){...}
```

If you relly need runtime dynamic storage you can allways fall back to dynamic.

Comment: Why wouldn't you make `set_values` also generic?

Comment: You could but I would assume under this pattern you are doing something specific based upon the input type.  If not then also make it generic.

Comment: Also not clear why you have converted it to a class instead of a generic `struct`.

Comment: sorry for the question but i a complete newbie to this. What do you mean with making it generic?

Comment: @DavidG - because that would mean it could be set to anything, but the OP wanted a specific dictionary entry to be tied down to a subset of possible types. So the Generic-ness is part of the definitoon and not of the operation.

Comment: @PhillipH That just begs a further question, why not add the function to the class and keep it generic?

Comment: @FutureCake it just means making a class or function able to accept multiple types.  Its a pretty large topic which is why I provided the link.

Comment: I made it a class for example only if the OP has good reasons to use a struct use away. 

If the op really want to restrict the type the best solution is to make the set_values functions static creator methods that are part of the answer class and give the answer class a private constructor.